# SQL Group by, Having, and Ordering (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have the following SQL:

```
select code, distance from places;
```

The output is below:

```
CODE      DISTANCE
106     386.895834130068
80      2116.6747774121 
80      2117.61925131453
106     2563.46708627407
```

I want to be able to just get a single code and the closest distance. So I want it to return this:

```
CODE      DISTANCE
106     386.895834130068
80      2116.6747774121
```

Still playing with Distinct and Group By.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select `code`, min(distance) as minimal_distance
from places
group by `code`
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is not working exactly? Can you provide an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 2):

```
select code, min(distance) as distance
from places
group by code
```

Here you've manual for GROUP BY: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Tutorials:

- http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php/
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  Code,
  MIN(Distance) AS closest_distance
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  Code
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select `code`, min(distance) as distance
from places
group by `code`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select code, min(distance) as mindist
from places
group by code
```